# Reading a line from a Stream and return immediately

Tags: java

Which method should i be using (and which class) for reading a line from a given InputStream, which in case there is no line to read, or actually in any case, returns immediatly?

For clarity, I want to know which class provides a method that reads a line from an InputStream, and returns Immedgiatly - e.g do not block if there is no line to read.

For exemple, BufferedReader.readLine() does block as far as i know.

Comment: what the close vote for?

Comment: Not my close vote, but your question confuses me and possibly others as well. Consider clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final String pollLine(final BufferedReader reader)
    throws IOException {
   /* pick a reasonable look ahead */
  reader.mark(512);
  while (reader.ready()) {
    final int ch = reader.read();
    if (ch == -1
            || Character.getType(ch) == Character.LINE_SEPARATOR) {
      reader.reset();
      return reader.readLine();
    } 
  }
  reader.reset();
  return null;
}
```

Sorry for any errors, I've typed this response on the small touchscreen keyboard of a cell phone.

To answer your question, you can query [`Reader.ready`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready()) to determine whether you can safely read without blocking.

> **Returns:**
>
> True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.

Comment: will reader.ready() return false if reader has nothing to read?

Comment: See my revised post; it has a direct quote from the Java 7 API specification.

Comment: just so you know, i implemented it by: return (in.ready()) ? in.readLine() : null; it works well. thanks for introducing me to ready() :)

Comment: @OfekRon that will only work for a stream where whole lines become available at a time. `ready` determines __one__ character can be read without blocking, not whether a whole line can be.